# Automatically route each URL to a specific .py file with mod_wsgi

Tags: python, apache, cgi, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I know that the traditional way to use `mod_wsgi` is to have one or a few routes declared in the config file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    WSGIScriptAlias /   /path/to/test_wsgi/app.py
```

and then handle all the possible URLs `example.com/hello`, `example.com/foo`, `example.com/foo/bar` directly from the server `app.py` (often running a framework like Bottle, Flask, etc.).

But is there a way to have an automatic correspondance

- http://example.com/hello.py  => automatically calls `./hello.py` script
- http://example.com/test/test.py =>  automatically calls `./test/test.py` script
- and more generally: http://example.com/path/to/script.py => automatically calls `./path/to/script.py` script

**without** having to manually register each handler in the `.htaccess` or `<VirtualHost>`?

**How can this be done with `mod_wsgi`?**

I know it's *not* the traditional usage, but I am curious if it can be done. If not, can we do this with CGI, FastCGI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation covers this use case. See:

- https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/configuration-guidelines.html#the-wsgiscriptalias-directive

The example uses:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /wsgi/ /usr/local/wsgi/scripts/
```

It isn't really a recommended approach since each script uses its own Python sub interpreter, all within the one process, so it can use up a lot of memory.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Oh I see... Is the following correct? **Without trailing slash**: refers to an actual file (e.g. `WSGIScriptAlias /myapp /usr/local/wsgi/scripts/myapp.wsgi`). **With trailing slash**: (*Both the mount point and the directory path must have a trailing slash.*) this maps any route `/wsgi/blah` to script `/usr/local/wsgi/scripts/blah`? If so, I think this tiny difference should be emphasized even more in the doc, with a concrete example of mapping, it would be awesome for future reference!

Comment: Trailing slash can be used when target is a file still, and you can leave out trailing slash when target is a directory. Whether or not you have a trailing slash has other implications though around how paths are constructed and whether redirections are performed by Apache in certain cases when target is a directory. For directories, general guideline is either have both URL and path have trailing slash, or both not have it. Which you use depends on your use case. For file target, usually would not use trailing slash on file path.

Comment: Thanks for this information. I think it would be great to include a few examples in the mod_wsgi documentation. Ex: With the setting `...` , http://example.com/path/to/hello.py would call script `...`, http://example.com/path/anotherone/test.py would call script `...`, etc.

Comment: You have already included examples for the 1st case @GrahamDumpleton: `WSGIScriptAlias /wiki /usr/local/wsgi/scripts/mywiki.wsgi`, `WSGIScriptAlias /blog /usr/local/wsgi/scripts/myblog.wsgi`, etc. which is very helpful. It would be great to add a few similar examples in the 2nd case, juste after *The second way of using the WSGIScriptAlias directive is to use it to map to a directory containing any number...* `WSGIScriptAlias /wsgi/ /usr/local/wsgi/scripts/`. What do you think?